# Streamlit change button size in python

Tags: python, button, streamlit

I have a program with an expander next to a button, but the button is smaller than the expander, and it bothers me a little. Is it possible to make the button bigger/make the expander's height smaller in *only python*. I have found solutions online using css, but I am just using python for my code.

Here is my code if anyone wants to look at it:

```py
    instructionCol, buttonCol = st.columns([4,1])
    with instructionCol:
        with st.expander("Instructions"):
            st.write("Pretend these are the instructions.")
    with buttonCol:
        st.button("\nRestart\n", on_click=board.reset)
```

Here is also what it looks like:

[image: st.expander and button are not aligned]

Comment: Hello, you can add css code inside your python code using `st.markdown(css_code, unsafe_allow_html = True)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `st.markdown(css, unsafe_allow_html=True)` directly inside the Python code:

```py
import streamlit as st

st.markdown(
    """
<style>
button {
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}
</style>
""",
    unsafe_allow_html=True,
)

instructionCol, buttonCol = st.columns([4,1])
with instructionCol:
    with st.expander("Instructions"):
        st.write("Pretend these are the instructions.")
with buttonCol:
    st.button("\nRestart\n", on_click=board.reset)
```

It gives:

[image: Aligned button and st.expander]

Notice that the button is now aligned with the expander (because I made it a bit bigger). Since you have found css solutions already, you can replace the css I generated with the one you found.